# How do I embed a JSON object in an HTTP POST form?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby, json

I want to embed a JSON object as a form parameter to send to the rails server.
here is what I have so far:

```
<% form_tag :action => :create, :controller => :objects do %>
    <%= text_field_tag :object %>
    <%= submit_tag %>
<% end %>
```

and the javascript to populate the field.  `data` is valid JSON.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$j(function(){
    jQuery("#proposal").val(JSON.stringify(data));
});
</script>
```

but, when the server receives the POST, I need to convert `params[:object]` to a hash, but It's doubly escaped, and even when using `.gsub("\\", "")`, JSON.parse appears bugged and doesn't actually convert to a JSON object from the string.

this is my JSON string recieved by the server:

```
"{\"name\":\"hello there,
 I am JSON!\",
\"template_id\":1,
\"variables\":{\"hello\":\"there\",
\"me\":\"you\"},
\"sections\":\"[{\\\"name\\\": \\\"Template Section\\\",
 \\\"contents\\\": [{\\\"id\\\": 1,
 \\\"name\\\": \\\"RENAMED!\\\"}]},
 {\\\"name\\\": \\\"section2\\\",
 \\\"contents\\\": [{\\\"name\\\": \\\"something\\\",
 \\\"body\\\": \\\"nothing\\\"},
 {\\\"id\\\": 2,
 \\\"name\\\": \\\"I renamed you\\\",
 \\\"variables\\\": {\\\"hello\\\": \\\"i'm amazing\\\"}}]}]\",
\"attachments\":\"[{\\\"media_id\\\": 1}]\"}"
```

Answer (score 1):

`data` is already a json serialized string you dont have to use `JSON.stringify()` which will again serialize it. Just set it as it is.

```
$j(function(){
    jQuery("#proposal").val(data);
});
```

Comment: this renders [object Object] in the text field.

Comment: How do you get the json string from server?

Comment: If it is hardcoded then you can simply define it as a well formed json object.